# Proper way to resolve an object going to be extended after resolving a different promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

I'm trying to make a *resource paginator* as a wrapper service to *restangular* :

```js
.factory('Collection', Collection)
 function Collection(Restangular) {
    var _route;
    ...

    function Collection(collectionName) {
        if (typeof collectionName === "undefined") {
            throw new Error("collection name is missing");
        }
        _route = collectionName;
    };

    Collection.prototype = {

        setData: function(response) {
            var data = response.data.plain();
            var _links = helpers.parse_link_header(response.headers('Link'));
            ...

            angular.extend(this, data);
        },

        load: function(perPage) {
            var scope = this;
            Restangular.all(_route).getList({'page':1, 'per-page':perPage})
            .then(function(collectionData) {
                scope.setData(collectionData);
            });
        },

        firstPage: function() {...},
        nextPage: function() {...}),
        ...
```

And this is how I'm using it inside controller :

```js
vm.images = new Collection('images');
vm.images.load(2);
```

`images.load()` will get data from server and once resolved it will send it to `setData()` method which will perform all the logic I need as parsing headers links, meta, .. then will extend the class with all data I'm expecting to have in my controller.

This works. It throws *few* logical errors like `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` on page load but once the Model get extended everything works fine and I can do those kind of things in my *HTML view file* :

```js
vm.images.nextPage();
vm.images.existNext();
vm.images.meta().$currentPage;
```

**My question is :**

What is the proper way to initialise *my collection* within an ui-router's state **resolve** method and be sure that my object is extended with server response before the controller is instantiated ?

**What I've tried so far :**

I know that a *promise* should be returned somehow so I made the `load` method look like :

```js
load: function(perPage) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var scope = this;
    _perPage = perPage;
    Restangular.all(_route).getList({'page':1, 'per-page':perPage})
    .then(function(collectionData) {
        var e = scope.setData(collectionData)
        deferred.resolve(e);
    }, 
    function(response) {
      console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
      deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

I made the `setData` return somthing :

```js
setData: function(response) {
    ...
    var newClass = angular.extend(this, data);
    return newClass;
},
```

Then I added this to my **$stateProvider.state** :

```js
resolve: {
  Collection: 'Collection',
  images: function(Collection){
    var images = new Collection('images');
    images.load(2);
    return images; 
  }
},
```

`vm.images = images` inside controller is getting data as expected but the same errors are thrown same as without adding it at all, so the code inside it is getting executed but I can't figure out how to make it wait for the model to be extended with server responses.

Any help would be appreciated & Thanks in advance !

Comment: try `return images.load(2)` to actually return the promise that's doing the loading.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball that was quick ! i've tried everything minus that. thanks ! you should post that as answer as u did answer it first

Comment: @SalemOuerdani That part of my answer was posted, I then took the time to point you the fact that you have a deferred *antipattern* in the *load* function, that you can make it cleaner and completed the answer, but anyway. Accept the answer or not, that's not a big deal for me.

Comment: yes thanks @MichaelP.Bazos I was just checking the second part of your answer. i didn't see it at first. it is true you did answer at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resolver, you should return the *load* promise:

```
images: function (Collection){
    var images = new Collection('images');
    return images.load(2);
}
```

Notice also that, in the load function, you could use the promise returned by `getList`:

```
load: function (perPage) {
    return Restangular.all(_route).getList({'page':1, 'per-page':perPage})
        .then(scope.setData)
        .catch(function (response) {
            return $q.reject('Error with status code ' + response.status);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! `return images.load(2)` did solve it & is enough but the `load` function returning the getList promise won't help in this case as I'm using `prototype` to make it look as a Class that I can initialise with the `new` param

Comment: no it won't get to `setData` if putting it out (err: scope.setData is not a function) I needed to build kind of a class following this (see: Sharing a model between controllers) : http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/